# Backup for OracleAS Portal

Tags: oracle, backup, portal

I am new to Oracle and I've developed an Oracle Portal using OracleAS Portal 10g release 2 (10.1.4). I need to move the application on another computer, and I was thinking of copying it on a CD but no matter I've tried I wasn't able to find the portal pages, nor the images or documents that I've included.

Can anybody help me please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer: I made a transport set. Transport sets are documented in the Portal Administrator's guide http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/portal.1014/b19305/cg_imex.htm#i1030999.